# Spicy nodes for silverlight

Tags: silverlight, graph

Are there any Graphing library where i can visual nodes like in the flash application over here http://www.spicynodes.org/, i searched silverlight and graphing library at codeplex and SO got a few results but then they don't contain any sample demo of what can be accomplished by them. I can't go on in circles (read that library , create sample silverlight app, test that app, asses the features, get approval from prod manager) over each and every project available.

- Hence does anyone have success using these libraries
- Is there a algorithm I can follow to achieve same
- Are there other resources which relates to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a similar component called Silverlight Spring Graph on Codeplex look here
http://slspringgraph.codeplex.com